# Creating a task for a backlog item automated in the release pipeline of VSTS

Tags: automation, release-management, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm looking for a possibility to create a task and attach it to a backlog-item from the release pipeline in Microsofts TFS/VSTS. So far I couldn't find anything that would make this possible. Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: To be clear, you want to create a Work item task, and parent it in the backlog automatically from the release pipeline.  When would this be triggered and to what parent?  When would these parameters be set?  I know you can automatically create a bug on failed builds

Comment: @xtreampb yes, that pretty much sums it up. The parent workitem would always be the same, but I would not care if I had to create one automatically as well. When it gets triggered doesn't matter that much as long as it can be done somewhere in the build pipeline. I guess if it possible, it would work anywhere in the pipeline

Comment: the easy part is to create the workitems (there are APIs and SDKs for this) but how you hand the parent work item to the pipeline? Pipelines cannot have parameters so you need an external service to query or a pseudo-artifact file listing the Id.

Comment: Could you add the log? Without it, it will be hard to answer the question. Please edit the Q&A and let us know when it can be reviewed. In the mean time the question will be closed.